# Automapper collections

Tags: automapper

I've read countless other posts and can't seem to figure out what's going on so it's time for some help.

I'm trying to map my domain entities which contain collections to dtos also containing collections.

Here's a primitive example; (i apologize in advance for the wall of code, i tried to keep it as short as possible):

**Entities**

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Bars = new List<Bar>();
    }
    public string Foo1 { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
public class Bar
{
    public string Bar1 { get; set; }
}
```

**Dtos**

```
public class FooDto
{
    public FooDto()
    {
        Bars = new List<BarDto>();
    }
    public string Foo1 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BarDto> Bars { get; set; }
}
public class BarDto
{
    public string Bar1 { get; set; }
}
```

**Maps**

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ICollection<Bar>, IEnumerable<BarDto>>();
```

**Tests**

```
// Arrange
var e = new Foo
{
    Foo1 = "FooValue1",
    Bars = new List<Bar>
    {
        new Bar
        {
             Bar1 = "Bar1Value1"
        },
        new Bar
        {
            Bar1 = "Bar2Value1"
        }
    }
};


// Act
var o = Mapper.Map<Foo, FooDto>(e);

// Assert

Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
Assert.AreEqual(e.Foo1, o.Foo1);
Assert.IsNotNull(o.Bars);
Assert.AreEqual(2, o.Bars.Count());
```

I'm not getting any configuration errors and Foo1 is mapping just fine.

o.Bars is a `Castle.Core.Interceptor.IInterceptor[]` and doesn't contain any of the values from my domain entity...

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ICollection<Bar>, IEnumerable<BarDto>>();
```

try simply:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Bar, BarDto>();
```

[AutoMapper will take care](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists%20and%20Arrays&referringTitle=Home) of the rest.

Comment: Go figure; i knew i overlooked something simple.  Can't give you credit for another 7 minutes.  Thanks for the help!